# Filter through array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, filter

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
const carsData = [
  {
    name: "Cars",
    collection: [
      { year: 2011, model: "B", price: 4400 },
      { year: 2015, model: "A", price: 32000 },
      { year: 2016, model: "B", price: 15500 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Trucks",
    collection: [
      { year: 2014, model: "D", price: 18000 },
      { year: 2013, model: "E", price: 5200 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Convertibles",
    collection: [
      { year: 2009, model: "F", price: 20000 },
      { year: 2010, model: "G", price: 8000 },
      { year: 2012, model: "H", price: 12500 },
      { year: 2017, model: "M", price: 80000 }
    ]
  }
];
```

and want to return a new array let's say `const newCarsData`(see below) where collection consists of only objects with year higher than 2013, so it will look like this:

```
const newCarsData = [
  {
    name: "Cars",
    collection:[
      { year: 2015, model: "A", price: 32000 },
      { year: 2016, model: "B", price: 15500 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Trucks",
    collection: [
      { year: 2014, model: "D", price: 18000 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Convertibles",
    collection: [
      { year: 2017, model: "M", price: 80000 }
    ]
  }
];
```

I tried filter method `collection.filter(x => x.year > 2013)` inside of for loop, but couldn't make it work. At the end my code looked like this

```
const newCarsData = getNewData(carsData);
let arr = [];
function getNewData(somedata) {
  for (let i = 0; i < somedata.length; i++) {
    // console.log(somedata[i].collection);
    for (let j = 0; j < somedata[i].collection.length; j++) {
      let arr.push(somedata[i].collection[j]);
      // console.log(somedata[i].collection[j]);
    }
    // return somedata[i].collection.filter(x => x.year > 2013);
  }
  return arr.filter(x => x.year > 2013);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: `where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you` lol . nice.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Will consider and will update the question with my unsolved code snippet

Comment: @d_oram two things, when nothing fits your bill, try reduce, second http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the collection is in another array inside the array items, you can't directly use `filter`. You can use `map` first then use `filter`.

```js
const carsData=[{name:"Cars",collection:[{year:2011,model:"B",price:4400},{year:2015,model:"A",price:32000},{year:2016,model:"B",price:15500}]},{name:"Trucks",collection:[{year:2014,model:"D",price:18000},{year:2013,model:"E",price:5200}]},{name:"Convertibles",collection:[{year:2009,model:"F",price:20000},{year:2010,model:"G",price:8000},{year:2012,model:"H",price:12500},{year:2017,model:"M",price:80000}]}]

const filteredCarData = carsData.map(carType => {
    return {
        ...carType,
        collection: carType.collection.filter(car => car.year>2013)
    }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredCarData))
```

The `...carType` notation collects the object properties in the new mapped object. If you have no other properties than `name`, you can instead do

```
const filteredCarData = carsData.map(carType => {
    return {
        name: carType.name,
        collection: carType.collection.filter(car => car.year>2013)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update your collection:

```
carsData.forEach(function(carData){
    carData.collection = carData.collection.filter(x => x.year > 2013);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it can be using reduce.

```
var res = carsData.reduce((acc, value) => {
    let data = { name: value.name, collections: value.collection.filter(v => v.year > 2013 )}
    return acc.concat(data)
}, [])
```

You can actually, replace the reduce with a map:

```
carsData.map(value => {
  return { name: value.name, collections: value.collection.filter(v => v.year > 2013 )}
})
```

Comment: But please go throught all the exercises in http://reactivex.io/learnrx

Comment: I usually use higher order functions but with nested data structure like this I wasn't able to come up with right logic, so i reached for loops and wrote some silly code as you see. Will do!